# PowerPoint VBA selecting only some shapes

Tags: vba, move, shapes, powerpoint

I am trying to make a subroutine in PowerPoint with VBA that will take 9 pictures that have been previously inserted and resized, and arrange them into 3 columns and 3 rows. I cannot figure out how to select a picture, move it, then select the next picture on the slide.

My VBA knowledge is limited mostly to using Excel, and since PowerPoint 2010 does not have a "Record Marco" button, this is my current pathetic attempt.

```
Sub ArrangeIn3x3()
Dim sldTemp As Slide
Dim lngTemp As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
    For Each sldTemp In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For lngCount = sldTemp.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            With sldTemp.Shapes(lngCount)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = 3 * 72
                .Left = (x + 0.2) * 72
                x = x + 1
                .Top = (y + 0.75) * 72
                y = y + 1
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This has your 3x3 grid hardcoded; you could extend it to take the number of rows/columns as parameters, to work out the size of the first image and supply that automatically, and any number of other enhancements, but this should do what you're after:

```
Sub NineUp()

    Dim sngInterRowSpace As Single
    Dim sngInterColSpace As Single
    Dim lRowCount As Long
    Dim lColCount As Long
    Dim sngLeft As Long
    Dim sngTop As Long
    Dim sngImageWidth As Single
    Dim sngImageHeight As Single
    Dim lShapeCount As Long '

    ' Define spacing between rows/columns
    sngInterRowSpace = 0.2 * 72
    sngInterColSpace = 0.2 * 72

    ' change these dimensions to match those
    ' of your images
    sngImageWidth = 2.36 * 72
    sngImageHeight = 2.17 * 72

    lShapeCount = 1
    sngTop = sngInterRowSpace

    For lRowCount = 1 To 3
        sngLeft = sngInterColSpace
        For lColCount = 1 To 3
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(lShapeCount)
                .Left = sngLeft
                .Top = sngTop
                sngLeft = sngLeft + sngImageWidth + sngInterColSpace
                lShapeCount = lShapeCount + 1
            End With
            'sngTop = sngTop + sngImageHeight + sngInterRowSpace
        Next
        sngTop = sngTop + sngImageHeight + sngInterRowSpace
    Next

End Sub
```